# Backbone.js with local storage

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

I want to use localstorage instead of the RESTful services provided by backbone.js.

My approach is to update the localstorage in the Backbone.sync method. This will not update the data in my collection however. So I need to do this seperatly.

Is there a better way to keep my localstorage and the models in the collection synchronised without having to repopulate the collection whenever I change the localstorage?

I am looking for a best practice approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following plugin [Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage)? Its pretty popular and overrides the sync so that it uses local storage.

Answer (score 0):

[An example Backbone application (todoMVC with localstorage)](http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html)

Maybe this annoted source example can help you!